# How to download videos from Dailymotion

Tags: download, dailymotion

I found that I can no longer download any videos from [Dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/en). It seems to me that the download link has been disabled.

Any idea how to download videos from Dailymotion?

Answer (score 1):

You download video from dailymotion on [force-download](http://www.force-download.com/?b=2).

Answer (score 0):

The [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006/) Firefox Extension will [download from DailyMotion](http://www.vidohe.com/site.php?site=12).

Comment: Ah, what if I am using Google Chrome? Any website that allows me to download the dailymotion videos?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Free Video Downloader](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_downloader/) (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You go to http://en.savefrom.net/ and then at the top you will see **for users** and **help**. If you are using Mozilla Firefox then click on **for users** and then install savefrom.net to Firefox. For more information go to **help**.

Answer (score 0):

Clipgrab is able to download videos from Dailymotion

It's free software for Windows, Mac and Linux 
http://clipgrab.org/faqs/supported-sites:

> Dailymotion is another video website with top-tier support by
>   ClipGrab. Videos from Dailymotion can be downloaded in HD, high and
>   low quality standard definition.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use Firefox because it's add-ons are amazing. 
Try to use video download helper in Firefox in combination with down them all add on. 
Downthem all is an add on that downloads at rapid speeds by breaking a file in parts. 
Hope you enjoy the download from daily motion

Comment: Same with this one, there's not a lot of actual content here.  Please see the [help] and [tour] for what Stack Exchange is all about.